# Getting Original Ip from Google Load Balancer with backend bucket and Cloudflare

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare and Google cloud backend bucket,

I check the RemoteIp in the Stackdriver log it is for Cloudflare and not for the original visitor IP.

Is there any way to retrieve the original visitor IP in Stackdriver logs?

Comment: From the CloudFlare support website: [*Cloudflare includes the original visitor IP address in the X-Forwarded-For and CF-Connecting-IP headers.*](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs-logging-visitor-IP-addresses). However, presumably Cloudflare will serve most requests from their own cache, so you'd be much better off looking at the *Cloudflare* logs.

Comment: The Issue is that I need the original Ip in the host address header since I am using a ready service and cannot configure the webserver

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to turn off the orange cloud next to the subdomain, so the Proxy status will be DNS only.

After applying this solution I get the original visitor Ip in the X-Forwarded-For header.

For more info check:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/understand-basics/proxy-modes#dns-only-mode